# how to reverse boolean and change text by clicking button?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to change boolean by clicking a button while changing the title of the button itself
but when I use this code below, it only changes to true (originally set 'false') and never comes back to false and the title of the button as well

```
@IBAction func widthCgBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if bold {
        bold == false
        txtBoldness.setTitle("Bold", for: .normal)
    } else {
        bold == true
        txtBoldness.setTitle("Normal", for: .normal)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What about debugging? Did you check the value of `bold` at the beginning of the function, and at the end? Just to be sure that's it's not overriden elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single = not == for assignment

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
IBAction func widthCgBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
bold = sender.isSelected
txtBoldness.setTitle("Normal", for: .normal) //For normal
txtBoldness.setTitle("Bold" , for: .selected) //For selected 
}
```